# Can Unity's "register-by-convention" resolve for abstract classes?

Tags: c#, interface, unity-container, abstract

I have a general generic interface for repositories.

I have a general generic abstract class that inherits from the general generic interface and implements some magic reflection methods for handling WCF services.

I then have an non-generic non-general abstract classes for each specific Repository. These abstract classes have implementations that i want to inject into their respective services with Unity.

Unity has a fancy "register-by-convention" function that registers interfaces and this works very nicely...

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.PerResolve);
```

My question is, how can i register my abstract classes and the implementation of each repository specific repository, like with the interfaces?

This seems possible in CastleWindsor and StructureMap so i am a bit at a loss of why the Enum's in RegisterTypes does not include Abstract Classes...

I have also tried registering it manually, with the thought of creating a reflection class that scans through the application and wires this up for me, if unity can't do it... i tried to do it like this:

```
        container.RegisterType<BaseToolRepository, ToolRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<BaseGenericRepository<ToolServiceClient,Tool>, BaseToolRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Tool>, BaseGenericRepository<ToolServiceClient, Tool>>();
```

But it will not resolve. Have i done something wrong? 
**Summary described** 
- ToolRepository is the implementation, 
- BaseToolRepository is the first abstract class that is specific. 
- BaseGenericRepsoitory is the Generic Abstract class that contains the reflection logic and 
- IGenericRepository is the interface that is on the bottom....

Comment: Unity cannot instantiate an abstract class.  Are you expecting it to generate a derived concrete class and instantiate that?

Comment: Yes of course :) Instansiate the derived concrete class of an abstract class, of the abstract class of the interface... Sorry if i did not explain myself to well....

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to resolve, but all can be achieved if you map all of the base types to the concrete type.  You are currently telling unity to map the IGenericRepository to an abstract class, so if you try to resolve the interface, Unity attempts to create an instance of the abstract class and fails.

Give this registration code a shot...

```
container.RegisterType<BaseToolRepository, ToolRepository>();
container.RegisterType<BaseGenericRepository<ToolServiceClient, Tool>, ToolRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Tool>, ToolRepository>();
```

Then all of these resolves should work...

```
container.Resolve<ToolRepository>();
container.Resolve<BaseToolRepository>();
container.Resolve<BaseGenericRepository<ToolServiceClient, Tool>>();
container.Resolve<IGenericRepository<Tool>>();
```

Also, here's some custom mappings you can use for the register-by-convention...

```
public static class WithCustomMappings
{
    public static Func<Type, IEnumerable<Type>> AggregateMappings(params Func<Type, IEnumerable<Type>>[] mappings)
    {
        return type =>
        {
            var mappedTypes = new List<Type>();
            foreach (var mapping in mappings)
                mappedTypes.AddRange(mapping(type));
            return mappedTypes.Distinct();
        };
    }

    public static Func<Type, IEnumerable<Type>> FromAllAbstractBaseClasses 
    {
        get
        {
            return type =>
            {
                var abstractBaseTypes = new List<Type>();
                var baseType = type.BaseType;
                while (baseType != null)
                {
                    if (baseType.IsAbstract)
                        abstractBaseTypes.Add(baseType);
                    baseType = baseType.BaseType;
                }
                return abstractBaseTypes;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

With its usage...

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithCustomMappings.AggregateMappings(WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces, WithCustomMappings.FromAllAbstractBaseClasses),
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.PerResolve);
```

Comment: The FromAllAbstractBaseClasses property gets it's data from the type.BaseType. However i cannot understand that this should be enough. I cannot see the internals of Unity, but i would think that there would be a list containing all the types used in AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies that i could loop through and find. When i debug the code, the FromAllAbstractClasses method gets called once, and only the first class in the list from AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies is -> type and this one is the one we get the base type from. As such i do not think this is doing what it is supposed to?